# An element adding unwanted margin space above the footer automatically

Tags: css, footer

Something is adding unwanted margin-top space to footer. I want to remove this but could not figure it out where it is coming from. Please see image below.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

```css
element.style {
    margin-top: 581px;
    display: block;
}
footer#main-footer {
    background: #F60;
    padding: 60px 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
HTML

<footer id="main-footer">
```

[image: footer image]

Comment: pls add your code too?

Comment: Please add a starting point in code to get a proper and quick answer to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve _Guessing_ from the picture, it maybe is added via JavaScript.

Comment: Add following code: `#main-footer { margin-top: 0}`

Comment: Html code would be helpful also.

Comment: It is adding this part of the code which I don't have: element.style {
    margin-top: 581px;
    display: block;
}

Comment: I've dropped your code on jsfiddle and it actually doesn't change the margin of the footer element. But just to make sure it also works for you, you can add the code which I've written above or just delete the `margin-top: 581px` property.

Comment: I have tried it but it will not solve the problem. The problem is that I don't have `element.style {
    margin-top: 581px;
    display: block;
}` property to delete in actual css file, it is coming from somewhere but I have no idea from where.

Comment: Did you try this? `#main-footer { margin-top: 0}`

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't work.

Comment: Just look, it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/wn57gz3v/

Comment: `element.style { margin-top: 581px; display: block; }` I need to delete this but I don't know where it is coming from. Inspection does not show a JavaScript causing this.

Comment: So just delete it. https://jsfiddle.net/wn57gz3v/1/   And everything works fine.

Comment: `element.style { margin-top: 581px; display: block; }` is disabling your code (`#main-footer { margin-top: 0}`)

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Drop your **whole** code on jsfiddle and I will tell you where it comes from.

Comment: bootstrap mt20 solved the problem:  `<footer id="main-footer" class="mt20" style="margin-top: 581px; display: block;">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap mt20 solved the problem: `<footer id="main-footer" class="mt20" style="margin-top: 581px; display: block;">`

Answer (score 0):

obviously some javascript (probably from a framework or template) is adding that `element.style` dynamically (i.e. a script is executed). You have to to deactivate at least that part of your (framework) script.
Since you give no more information and code, that's all that can be said to help you.

ADDITION: Note what is written at the bottom right of your image: that's where this stuff comes from...

ADDITION 2: You can try to add `#main-footer { margin-top: 0 !important;}`, but that's not really a good solution...

Comment: I think that he is trying to bite code which is too difficult for him at this moment. This is how it is when you are trying to do some amazin' stuff while you are just a beginner.

Comment: I tried to remove all JS files one by one but it did't make the change, maybe it was already added there and removing files would not make a change back. I will have a look and update you. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried that also but it still didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

With limited details in the question and no way to reproduce the issue I can suggest 2 things:

1. As a WORKAROUND you can use footer#main-footer { margin-top: 0px !important }. Though this is not recommended. https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/
2. Alternatively if you wish to debug the issue, start removing JS references from your HTML one by one. There will be some JS code that is causing this. When you remove reference to that code your footer will be fine (without using the workaround mentioned above). Once you have identified the JS file you can debug that code to check why its adding `margin-top`.